# lightdm crash (once) & thereafter login screen shows "failed to authenticate" - impossible to login

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen

OS: ubuntu 20.04 with lightdm
HW: Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB

**History**: this system has worked for well over a year without issues.

There was a random crash of the sound system (this has happened before), my normal cure for this is to reboot. Usually it works.

This time, I could not log in after reboot. The lightdm greeting screen seems to want to auto login (I disabled auto login a long time ago) and shows the error message `failed to authenticate`.

How do I investigate and fix this problem?

### Some things I tried:

1. `reboot` - no impact, may have caused the initial problem
2. `apt reinstall lightdm; reboot` - no impact
3. commented out kwallet in pam configuration of lightdm - no impact other than a few error messages less in the logs
4. `ssh` - remote login works, this is my way in (tty also works)

Edit:

5. removed and reinstalled lightdm - no impact other than changing the login splash screen

   ```
   apt purge lightdm
   apt update
   apt install lightdm
   dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
   reboot
   ```
6. created /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf as below - it did add a 'login' button to the login screen, but there still isn't any box to enter a username or a password, so I can't login.

   ```
   [SeatDefaults]
   greeter-show-manual-login = true
   greeter-hide-users = false
   allow-guest = false
   ```

Note: my system does not have gdm.

### Logs & files:

`/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` does not exist:

```
> ls -alR /etc/lightdm
/etc/lightdm:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Sep 13 23:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 151 root root 12288 Sep 13 22:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Feb  7  2020 lightdm.conf.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   466 Feb  7  2020 users.conf

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  7  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 13 23:38 ..
```

`/var/log/apport.log` shows many repeats of the following lines, one for each retry or reboot:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 2458) <date/time>: executable: /usr/sbin/lightdm (command line "lightdm --session-child 13 20")
ERROR: apport (pid 2458) <date/time>: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 2458) <date/time>: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

Crash report (around the first reboot, not sure whether it happened before or after my first reboot to try and solve my sound system issue):

```
> ls -al /var/crash/
total 228
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie   4096 Sep 13 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root       4096 Dec 15  2020 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie 219359 Sep 13 17:14 _usr_sbin_lightdm.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie      0 Sep 13 17:14 _usr_sbin_lightdm.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie     37 Sep 13 17:14 _usr_sbin_lightdm.0.uploaded
```

`/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` (last few, relevant lines):

```
[+6.37s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.30.0 api=1 resettable=false
[+7.24s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for ubuntu
[+7.24s] DEBUG: Session pid=2455: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'ubuntu'
[+8.71s] DEBUG: Session pid=2455: Terminated with signal 11
[+8.71s] DEBUG: Session: Failed during authentication
[+8.71s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user ubuntu: Authentication stopped before completion
[+8.71s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was an update that did not fully complete and corrupted some links in the `snap` directory of the user's home.

Below I show a corrected directory structure, before correction the `current` links were pointing at numbers / directory names that did not exist.

```
> tree -L 2 snap
snap
├── chromium
│   ├── 1383
│   ├── 1417
│   ├── 1740
│   ├── 1816
│   ├── common
│   └── current -> 1816
├── rpi-imager
│   ├── 171
│   ├── 185
│   ├── common
│   └── current -> 185
└── ubuntu-mate-welcome
    ├── 574
    ├── 627
    ├── 648
    ├── common
    └── current -> 648
```

Answer (score 0):

I just yesterday had an issuethat lightdm would not log me ion anymore but that was on 18.04. what I did to resolve thisd was:

```
# apt purge lightdm
# apt update
# apt install lightdm
# dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
# reboot
```

Which fixed it for me, good luck!

Comment: Thank you but that did not solve my problem. All it did is change the login splash screen.

Comment: @asoundmove Sorry to hear, have you tried using another dm instead of lightdm?  Give gdm or xdm a try...?